# Summarizing in "R"

Tags: r, logistic-regression, data-analysis

I am performing logistic regression in r.During the decile analysis stage
i am trying to do the following :-

```
decile_sum_training = summarize(decile_grp,total_cnt= n(),churn_cnt= sum(CHURN),
                                not_churn_cnt= total_cnt- churn_cnt)
```

but i get the following error when i use summarize(Hmisc) : -

```
Error in summarize(decile_grp, total_cnt = n(), churn_cnt = sum(CHURN),  : 
  argument "by" is missing, with no default
```

Please suggest something.

Comment: try to use `summary` instead of `summarize`

Answer (score 1):

Use a constant "by":

```
..., by = rep(1, nrow(decile_grp))
```